# Starting an Activity automatically after loading Fragment

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments

I am still new to android concepts and programming.

I am using Google Cloud Messaging Service to send notification for android application.

I want to start a GCMActivity with no Layout, which will register a device and get the registration id and will send it to backend. After completing this task it will go back to or show a particular fragment.

I have tried it by starting an activity with intent in Fragment's  onCreateView() method and is giving error. I am not sure how to implement automatic activity. Any thoughts guys?

Comment: its giving an error? what error?

Comment: You can probably have a splash screen, do your background services(register your device,get id) once its authenticated on post execute load your Map..

Comment: please post the error it is giving as well

Comment: I am getting **java.lang.nullpointerexception** but anyway, I have followed @AndroidEnthusiast comment and modified the logic and is working fine now. Thanks Guys for suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about registering the device in your Main Activity instead of the Fragment's OnCreateView.

So for example onCreate() or onResume() of your activity.

So whatever the main activity is launched it handles registration or checks if there is a previous registration.

Then you load whatever fragment you need to.